# GStreamer fakesink can not get data

Tags: gstreamer

I run GStreamer exsample:qglwtextureshare. But I found it will crash at 
qglrenderer.cpp Line168 Q_ASSERT (gst_is_gl_memory (mem)); I modified the pipeline like this : 
`m_pipeline =
        GST_PIPELINE (gst_parse_launch
        ("videotestsrc ! "
            "video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, "
            "framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! "
            "fakesink sync=1", NULL));` because gleffects effect=5 will pop error can not get fisheye shader.

And I don't change otherthings. I don't know why it can not get the frame data. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: What is your expectation here? `fakesink` is a dummy sink that exists to have a sink - but all it does is discarding data..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to get each frame from video. So I use fakesink, and in its callback function, I get the buffer, and then send it to QT QOpenGLWidget to show it. My old idea is using appsink, but it is very slow, then I find this way.

Comment: `appsink` is the way to go then. If you make it manually there is no faster way. Maybe you want to use a regular sink and `GtVideoOverlay` interface which is probably faster. There are Qt sink sinks for embedding in Qt applications for exactly that purpose too.

Comment: What is GtVideoOverlay? Could you tell more detail? QT is very unfriendly, it is not compatible between each version. That's the reason  we use GStreamer, rather than use QtGStreamer class.

Comment: Check the docs as https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/GstVideoOverlay.html most video sinks implement this interface. You can then pass a drawing surface to the sink and it renders the video into this surface.

Comment: OK,Thank you.  I changed to your way.